# Spring Security /j_spring_security_check without JSP

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, backbone.js, spring-security

I need clean URL rather than the extension appended. I'm using the Backbone.js framework in my UI. I have a view built that gathers a username and password and performs a restful request to `/j_spring_security_check`.

For some reason, username and password are not being seen by the `/j_spring_security_check` end point.

Here is the request I'm performing in backbone:

```
loginModel.save( loginModel.toJSON(), {
    success: _.bind(function(response) {
        Backbone.history.navigate('', {trigger: true});
    }, this),
    error: function() {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

I've tried making the request with the j_username and j_password as attributes of the model as such and setting the url to `/j_spring_security_check`.

I've also tried passing the params directly in the url as such:

```
/jspring_security_check?j_username=X&j_password=Z
```

Both ways get into my auth providers authenticate method but the *Credentials* and *Principal* are both blank strings so the auth fails.

When I make my requests I can see in the browser's developer tools that request payload gets setnt down:

```
{j_username: "a", j_password: "a"} j_password: "a" j_username: "a"
```

What is the correct way to make a request to `/j_spring_security_check` without using a JSP form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at Spring's class which performs authentication which is
/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java

```
private boolean postOnly = true;

public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
    }
```

You are sending a GET request with /jspring_security_check?j_username=X&j_password=Z, when it expects a POST request.

The request must be a POST request with Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and two parameters. The body of the request should not be a JSON object.

I suggest re-designing your login and not to use Ajax.

j_spring_security_check is not designed to be called via Ajax from a login page. It is designed to accept a POST request from an HTML form, and then to render an application main page in HTTP response to login form submission.

What j_spring_security_check does is that it authenticates the user and if authentication is successful, it creates a session and re-directs the user to the main screen, otherwise it re-directs the user to the "login failed" screen. j_spring_security_check returns 302 HTTP code which is a re-direct.

RESTful login is possible, but you will have to configure j_spring_security_check to respond not with a successful (or failed) login view, but with JSON, so you will have to write custom login handlers on the Java side. I did that once, and that made code (both Java and ExtJS) so complicated that I fell back to form-based login. After all, Facebook and Google use form  submission for login, and that's pretty normal. In my case swithing to Ajax REST login was not worth the effort.

Another advantage of form submission is that the web browser can remember login and password, which is not possible with Ajax-based login, and I think that is the reason why both Google and Facebook use form submission.

But if you decide you still need Ajax-based login (which I strongly discourage because of complexity of implementation and because user experience will ne hurt by the browser's password manager not working) then you will have to create two Spring MVC controllers, one for successful login (loginSucessController), another for login failure (loginFailureController), both controllers should return a uniform JSON response with login status. Then configure Spring Security to use the two controllers above

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
               "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<sec:http>
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**"/>
            <sec:http-basic/>
            <sec:form-login default-target-url="/loginSucessController" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailureController"/>
            <sec:logout/>
    </sec:http>
</beans>
```

Of course, you will have to create mappings and implementations for loginSucessController and  loginFailureController, I skipped that part.

loginSucessController should return

```
{ "loginStatus": 1 }
```

and loginFailureController should return

```
{ "loginStatus": 0 }
```

You also will have to create a third MVC controller to detect if the user has already signed in to decide if the login form has to be shown when the user returns back to the application web page, use org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder#getContext

Comment: The issue I have with using a JSP is my backbone views all use HTML templates to build the html views. So in order to use a JSP page I would have to go build that one page without backbone. I'd rather just build the entire application using the backbone framework.

Comment: What is the best way to go about using a JSP login form while I'm using backbone? Is it possible to embed the jsp into a backbone view?

Comment: When I was developing an application with ExtJS, I created a separate static HTML web page for login which didn't use javascript at all. The user was re-directed to ExtJS application html file upon successful login, that is the simplest approach.